# R RSelenium's rsDriver() - Failed to connect to localhost port 4567

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver

Always seem to struggle with RSelenium, and today is no different. Here are the versions of R and RSelenium we are using, as well as our function call and the error we are receiving.

[image]

Here is our local Google Chrome version

[image]

We downloaded the `chromedriver` executable, but I do not see how we can pass this as a parameter to the `rsDriver()` function? Perhaps if we pass the chromedriver executable as a parameter somehow, we will have more luck with this?

Any recommendations on how we can get RSelenium driver up and running locally on our machine? Could it be that these issues are due to us having the latest Mac ARM chip?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following approach. You need to install Docker.

```
library(RSelenium)   

url <- "https://www.google.com/"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$setTimeout(type = "implicit", 2000)
remDr$navigate(url)
```

You can also consider the following approach

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)

url <- "https://www.google.com/"
port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
pJS <- wdman::phantomjs(port = port)
remDrPJS <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs", port = port)
remDrPJS$open()
remDrPJS$navigate(url)
remDrPJS$screenshot(TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the localhost port isn't being detected properly. Utilizing the answer previously provided, I was able to detect a second open port to use. Additionally, the wdman package allows you to control the download of the web browser binary utilized - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wdman/readme/README.html. Here is my similar code that loads the chrome browser using wdman:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)

url <- "https://www.google.com/"
port <- as.integer(4444L + rpois(lambda = 1000, 1))
port <- 5462L
chromeR <- wdman::chrome(port = port)
remDrChrome <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", port = port)
remDrChrome$open()
remDrChrome$navigate(url)
remDrChrome$screenshot(TRUE)
```